# Dynamic data exchange (DDE) link termination

Tags: winapi

I am reading about the Dynamic Data Exchange protocol [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468830(v=vs.85).aspx).  It uses global atom tables to share data between applications.

My questions are:

- What would happen if a DDE link between two application is interrupted or terminated?  If it was interrupted, can we continue it with the same link? Would data be lost?
- When a DDE connection is closed, what would happen to the atom table created to exchange data?

It would be great if someone can explain, or direct me to an article to read and further understand the DDE protocol.

Comment: Who still uses DDE nowadays?  It is a long deprecated technology. There are much better ways to exchange data between processes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, but I am reading about it for research purpose. Do you know any good source that I can refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want to use DDE you should use [DDEML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648713(v=vs.85).aspx). With this functions you get handles or ids to registered objects.

MS always recommended to use DDEML after it was introduced and to not use the pre DDE interface. If connections got broken, you have to reconnect.

If you allocate/register/aquire elements you have to free them, even if things fail. This includes also the complete internal string handling.